# How to enable parallel in scipy.optimize.differential_evolution?

Tags: python-3.x, differential-evolution

I am trying to find the global minimum of a function using differential_evolution from scipy.optimize. As explained in the scipy reference guide, I should set in the options:
updating='deferred',workers=number of cores

However, when I run the code, it freezes and does nothing. How can I solve this issue, or is there any better way for parallelizing the global optimizer?

The following is in my code:

```
scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(objective, bnds, args=(), 
            strategy='best1bin', maxiter=1e6,
            popsize=15, tol=0.01, mutation=(0.5, 1),    
            recombination=0.7, seed=None,
            callback=None, disp=False, polish=True,
            init='latinhypercube', atol=0,
            updating='deferred',workers=2)
```

Comment: Also when I use Spyder to run this code, it gives me the following error:
differential_evolution() got an unexpected keyword argument 'updating'

Comment: I installed conda instead of using IDLE, and now it works from terminal

Comment: following up on your comment to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831551/parallel-multithread-differential-evolution-in-python/51003128#comment91836148_51003128) , I'll give it a shot and let you know. Could you just add what objective, bounds, and scipy version you're using?
Also, where did you find about the `workers` argument? I can't find it on the [scipy.optimize.differential_evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) page

Answer (score 7):

Came across the same problem myself. The support for parallelism in `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution` was added in version `1.2.0` and the version I had was too old. When looking for the documentation, the top result also referred to the old version. The newer documentation can instead be found at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html.

I use virtualenvironment and *pip* for package management, and to upgrade to the latest version of *scipy* I just had to run `pip install --upgrade scipy`. If using *anaconda*, you might need to do e.g. `conda install scipy=1.4.1`.

In order to activate the parallelism, set the `workers` flag to something `> 1` for a specific number of cores or `workers=-1` to use all available cores.

---

One caveat: Don't make the same mistake as me and try to run the differential evolution directly in the top level of a Python script on Windows because it won't run. This is due to how `multiprocessing.Pool` functions. Specifically, instead of the following:

```
import scipy.optimize

def minimize_me(x, *args):
    ...  # Your code
    return result

# DO NOT DO LIKE THIS
...  # Prepare all the arguments
# This will give errors
result = scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(minimize_me, bounds=function_bounds, args=extraargs,
                                               disp=True, polish=False, updating='deferred', workers=-1)
print(result)
```

use the code below:

```
import scipy.optimize

def minimize_me(x, *args):
    ...  # Your code
    return result

# DO LIKE THIS
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...  # Prepare all the arguments
    result = scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(minimize_me, bounds=function_bounds, args=extraargs,
                                                   disp=True, polish=False, updating='deferred', workers=-1)
    print(result)
```

See this post for more info about parallel execution on Windows: [Compulsory usage of if __name__=="__main__" in windows while using multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi)
Note that even if not on Windows, it's anyway a good practice to use `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Comment: Freezes for me unfortunatley, someone knows why?

Comment: @Varlor probably something specific to your code, maybe share some details?