# SciPy Differential Evolution: doesn't run on multiple cores even if workers = -1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-evolution

**Context:**

- I'm developing an optimizer by using SciPy's differential evolution package. I get some good results with worker = 1, but I would like to speed up the runtime.
- I checked the following thread already regarding [How to enable parallel in scipy.optimize.differential_evolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888676/how-to-enable-parallel-in-scipy-optimize-differential-evolution) Even if I add `if __name__ == "main":` and set workers = -1, the runtime is exactly the same. I tested my code on my local machine (2 physical, 4 logical processors) or on our server environment (16 cores)
- I tested the following use case https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-code-using-multiprocessing-in-python-36e4e703213e. Changing the number of workers does impact the runtime, so parallel processing work on my laptop and server as well.
- Consequently, my hypothesis is that the way I defined my objective and constraint function might be the problem.

**Pseudo Code:**

- The code is for work, so I can't share it. My objective and constraint functions need a lot of constants, hence I wrapped them into a Class. I know that the `args` parameter is for that, but the constraint function doesn't have that parameter.
- The code structure looks the following way:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(configuration, array1, array2, dataframe):
        # assigning attributes so that 
        self.something = datafame[column1]
        ...
   
    def obj(self, x):
        # based on the initialized values + optimized parameters, it calculates the objective

    def cons(self, x):
        # based on the initialized values + optimized parameters, it calculates the constraint violations
```

Then, I create a class instance `o = MyClass()` and call the differential evolution function with the class module: `differential_evolution(func = o.obj, ...)`.

**Question:**

- Has anyone faced the following issue, i.e. even if you set multiple workers the code runs on one?
- Do you have any suggestions on how to better design the objective and constraint functions so that they are eligible for parallel processing?

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, I would rename the `obj` method to `__call__`, then use the object as `differential_evolution(o)`. Then I would check that `MyClass` pickleable.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that there is overhead from `multiprocessing`, so you'll only see a speedup commensurate with the number of processors used if the objective function calculation time is much larger than the overhead.